# LibGDX - Last thing that gets called

Tags: android, libgdx

I don't know where to put my   `Debug.stopMethodTracing();`

What is the last function that gets called before activity is destroyed (while running LibGDX)?

**Edit:** I tried to put it in overriden method onDestroy() from AndroidApplication, but it didn't seem to get called whenever i pressed home button or killed the activity in eclipse.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The libGDX `ApplicationListener` has `pause` and `dispose` callbacks that will be invoked on the exit path.  The `pause` is called when exiting (not just a suspend/resume), so its where I persist the state of my game.

See http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/ApplicationLifeCycle

Comment: I can't manage to get access to android.os.Debug in my Java project where ApplicationListener is implemented. I can get access just from my Android project.

Comment: Ah, right.  The usual work-around in libGDX for this sort of platform-access problem is to wrap the API or use reflection to access it.  For a simple method with no parameters or return value, reflection is probably the easiest way? See http://www.badlogicgames.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=1330